# suitable data structure for set (graph) partition

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, set, data-partitioning

I need to store data grouping nodes of a graph partition, something like:

[node1, node2] [node3] [node4, node5, node6]

My first idea was to have just a simple vector or array of ints, where the position in the array denoted the node_id and it's value is some kind of group_id

The problem is many partition algorithms rely on operating on pairs of nodes within a group. With this method, I think I would waste a lot of computation searching through the vector to find out which nodes belong to the same group.

I could also store as a stl set of sets, which seems closer to the mathematical definition of a partition, but I am getting the impression nested sets are not advised or unnecessary, and I would need to modify the inner sets which I am not sure is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: boost graph library will possibly be mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to do with the sets, you could try a [disjoint set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). In this structure, each element has a method `find` that returns the "representative" of the set it belongs to.

A C++ implementation is available in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are two good data structures that come to mind.

The first data structure (and one that's been mentioned here before) is the disjoint-set forest, which gives extraordinarily efficient implementations of "merge these two sets" and "what set is x in?".  However, it does not support the operation of splitting groups apart from one another.

The other structure I'd recommend is a link/cut tree.  This structure lets you build up partitions of a graph that can be joined together into trees.  Unlike the disjoint set forest, the tree describing the partition can be cut into smaller trees, allowing you to break partitions into smaller groups.  This structure is a bit less efficient than the union/find structure, but it still supports all operations in amortized O(lg n).